# Dialog view animates "manually" but not when using an animation

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to apply a custom animation to show and hide a `Dialog` and have come across a certain problem.

A `View` provides two method for animation which are `.animate()` which I call a "manual" animation and `.startAnimation(Animation animation)` which receives an `Animation` object.

I access the dialog's view by calling `alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView()` and try to animate it using `startAnimation` but that doesn't work. Only if I use the `animate` function I can animate it.

Here is a code example that, as far as I know, should return the same results but reproduces the problem I'm dealing with:

```java
AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create(); // Create the dialog
View decorView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView(); // Access the dialog's view
// The animation below works fine
decorView.animate().rotationXBy(45).setDuration(500).start(); // Animate it "manually"
// Create an animation instance
RotateAnimation scaling = new RotateAnimation(0, 45);
scaling.setDuration(500);
scaling.setFillAfter(true);
// This animation does NOT work
decorView.startAnimation(scaling);
```

I have tried the same code with other views and it works normally so I guess there is some peculiarity for dialogs that break the functionality?

I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong and, if possible, how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going other way instead of using dialogs but with them, you really have to manually create your animations step by step instead of using those helpful classes that the platform provides.

I thought it could be some problem related to the view not being ready for the `Animation` and even started it inside a `decorView.post(Runnable)` but the same results were obtained.

If anyone else tries this approach (seriously don't, create your own view and animate it normally, you'll run into even worse problems animating the dialog's dismissal) be aware that animating a dialog is not so easy. Maybe look for libraries that do it.